# How to get complement of path in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, path, path-effects

I would like to get complement of this path in Inkscape.
So, black would become white and what is white would become black .
Also, circular shape should be preserved. 
How to do this ?

[image: path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a circle and position it behind the path so that it perfectly covers it, then select both the circle and the path and choose **Path>Difference** in the menu.

[image: inkscape workflow]

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape, you can change the colours of the fills and strokes for any object to anything you want. Just select an object and change the stroke/fill attribute to the colour you want.

As for inverting the colours of an entire selection, simply select everything you want to invert and hit Filters > Colours > Invert

For the background, you can change it to white in document properties of Inkscape.

Comment: I want that complement of this path is also a path.  I did manage to invert it with Filters > Colours > Invert but I didn't get a path.